# How do I prevent automatic line break in my heading tag?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

In the following picture as you can see "Colton Smith" is coming in two lines. What should I do to prevent this? I want to display in the same line.
Here is my code

> 

```html
<div class="row mt-5" id='imag'>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-1">
            <img src="images/image-colton.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3" id="intro">
            <h6>Colton Smith</h6>
            <h6>Verified Buyer</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <p>
            "We needed the same printed design as the one we had                  ordered aweek prior. Not only did they find the                      original order, but we alsoreceived it in time.                      Excellent!"
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

[here is the image of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AILSk.png)

Comment: I assume this is bootstrap, the class col-lg-3 is restricting the elements width to fit all the content within its width. col-lg-1 will take up exactly 8.3 percent of its parents width, which is row, so your col-lg-3, is taking up roughly 25% of the parents row, so you need to increase that elements width using a larger col class.

Answer (score -1):

In your code change `<div class="col-lg-3" id="intro">` to `<div class="col-lg-11" id="intro">`